# visual audio monitor/global spectrum monitor

Tags: windows-7, hdmi

i am trying to find a standalone spectrum visualizer that would allow me to monitor any output, specially surround, i send to my home theater via HDMI.

i am familiar with this foobar's [spectrum analizer](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=Foobar2000:Components_0.9/Peakmeter_Spectrum_%28foo_uie_vis_peakmeter_spectrum%29) plugin and i would like to find something just that but that monitors any audio output in windows 7.

anyone knows a program that does this?